# Used Predict function on New Dataset with different Columns

Tags: r, regression, predict

Using "stackloss" data in R, I created a regression model as seen below:

```
    stackloss.lm = lm(stack.loss ~  Air.Flow + Water.Temp + Acid.Conc.,data=stackloss)

stackloss.lm 
newdata = data.frame(Air.Flow=stackloss$Air.Flow, Water.Temp= stackloss$Water.Temp, Acid.Conc.=stackloss$Acid.Conc.)
```

Suppose I get a new data set and would need predict its "stack.loss" based on the previous model as seen below:

```
#suppose I need to used my model on a new set of data
stackloss$predict1[-1] <- predict(stackloss.lm, newdata)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "predict1", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 21
```

Is their a way to used the predict function on different data set with the same columns but different rows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is just an example, like the `stackloss$predict1[-1]` it the new data set with different number of row. I need to used my original model to predict the `y` of a new dataset to see if its accurate. Like example I created a model to see the price of a car insurance and my model would be used by the company for all cars so I would need to used my  model on multiple datasets.

Comment: `stackloss2 <- stackloss[-1,]`
`stackloss2["predict1"] <- NULL`

`stackloss2$predict1 <-  predict(stackloss.lm, newdata) `

Comment: The error says number of rows don't match. I need to used predict function on different datasets with different number of rows.

Comment: I really meant `stackloss$predict1[-1]` because I am trying to used predict in datasets for with different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can predict into a new data set of whatever length you want, you just need to make sure you assign the results to an existing vector of appropriate size.

This line causes a problem because

```
stackloss$predict1[-1] <- predict(stackloss.lm, newdata)
```

because you can't assign and subset a non-existing vector at the same time. This also doesn't work

```
dd <- data.frame(a=1:3)
dd$b[-1]<-1:2
```

The length of `stackloss` which you used to fit the model will always be the same length so re-assigning new values to that data.frame doesn't make sense. If you want to use a smaller dataset to predict on, that's fine

```
stackloss.lm = lm(stack.loss ~  Air.Flow + Water.Temp + Acid.Conc.,data=stackloss)

newdata = head(data.frame(Air.Flow=stackloss$Air.Flow, Water.Temp= stackloss$Water.Temp, Acid.Conc.=stackloss$Acid.Conc.),5)

predict(stackloss.lm, newdata)
       1        2        3        4        5 
38.76536 38.91749 32.44447 22.30223 19.71165
```

Since the result has the same number of values as `newdata` has rows (n=5), it makes sense to attach these to `newdata`. It would not make sense to attach to `stackloss` because that has a different number of rows (n=21)

```
newdata$predcit1 <- predict(stackloss.lm, newdata)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a follow up, what if I add say new rows in the original dataset, can I still used predict function?

Comment: Yes. I don't see why not.

Comment: but will it automatically predict the `yhat` of the new rows. Thanks